# Resize div based on the video size

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I've created a button in a video and I've added a `<div>` on the top of that button. But when I try to resize that video I want that button to resize with that video i.e. I want that `<div>` to cover that button in the video nicely even when I try to resize the video.

**UPDATE**

The white box is the div--->

[image]

This is what happens when i try to resize the video--->

[image]

I tried using percentage values in the CSS but still it's not working maybe because of the outer black bars.

**UPDATE 2**

```
.start-button {
  width: 42%;
  height: 19%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  left: 5%;
  margin: 20% 0 0 24%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**HTML Structure**

```
<div class="container">
        <video id="sortedd" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls="false" preload="60" data-setup="{}">
            <source src="sortedd.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
        </video>
        <div class="option-panel">
            <!--    Starting of the quiz    -->
            <div class="start-button"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give some more information. Source would be nice, but also an explanation of what goes wrong, maybe with a screenshot, and what you've tried to make it work.

Comment: I've updated the question. Sorry for the delay i was busy with my exams. I know it's not perfect can you please suggest me something that i can try percentage values are not working.

Comment: We need to know the html structure....

Comment: Okay I've added the HTML Structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is how I did it:

**The HTML Structure**

```
   <div class="container">
        <video id="sortedd" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls="false" preload="60" data-setup="{}" width="100vw" height="56.25vh">
            <source src="sortedd.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
        </video>
        <div class="play-button"></div>
   </div>
```

**The CSS Styling**

```
.play-button
{
  background-color: red;
  width: 44vw;
  height: 9.687vw;
  background: red;
  max-height: 18vh;
  max-width: 77.222vh;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2147483647;
}
```

After a lot of hit and trials I somehow managed to make it work. Can anyone please explain me the relation between Maximum values of height and width and the normal height and width.